# How do I assign the digits of int to array c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Bear with me, I'm fairly new.

What I am trying to do is get what the user inputs to be separated into digits into an array so for example:

```
    int digits[10] = {0}   //initialize
    int input = 12345;     // length was defined earlier, and in this case is "5"

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

        digits[i - 1] = (input / (10 ^ (i - 1))) % 10;      // supposed to seperate digits in reverse order
                                                            // 12345 --> digits[] --> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
                                                            // currently not working
    }
```

I was testing it to makes sure that i was doing this right and have the array printed to the screen but I got back: 11234

I tried different numbers and for example, 22222 prints out : 79702

code for printing the array:

```
        for (int k = length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            cout << digits[k] << endl;
    }
```

I know I'm missing something, but thanks in advance

Comment: Wow! A well-worded, and correctly-formatted question. Well done! It's rare to see such a good quality question from a new user!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your math is exactly correct, but you have made a very reasonably syntax mistake.

The `^` operator in C++ is [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), not exponentiation. You will want to use `std::pow(base, exponent)`.

Comment: Oh wow. I probably should've looked that up before assuming. Ha! Well thanks